# Trouble formatting a string with multiple quotation marks

Tags: xcode, swift, terminal, applescript, osascript

I am making a NSTask which runs `osascript` to gracefully quit an application instead of a `killall/kill` command.

I have this:

```
let killtask = NSTask()
killtask.launchPath = "/usr/bin/killall"
killtask.launchPath = "/usr/bin/osascript"
killtask.arguments = ["-e","'quit app", ""Transmission"""'"]
killtask.launch()
```

The troublesome line is the arguments I'm trying to pass.

The command in terminal is like this:

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'quit app "Notes"'
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I format the arguments so it gets all the single and double quotation marks actually used in the command?

**EDIT**

Running

```
killtask.arguments = ["-e \'quit app \"Transmission\"\'"]
```

Gives me:

```
0:2: syntax error: A unknown token can’t go here. (-2740)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct way to [parameterize an AppleScript run via `osascript`](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/osascript.html):

```
let appName = "Transmission"

let killtask = NSTask()
killtask.launchPath = "/usr/bin/osascript"
killtask.arguments = ["-e", "on run {appName}", 
                      "-e", "  quit app appName", 
                      "-e", "end run",
                      appName]
killtask.launch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delimit the quotes, and make sure your arguments are correct.

```
let killtask = NSTask()
killtask.launchPath = "/usr/bin/osascript"
killtask.arguments = ["-e","'quit app \"Transmission\"'"]
killtask.launch()
```

If the arguments do not work, try putting a backslash in front of the single quotes (`'`) too.

Comment: I'm getting `0:1: syntax error: A unknown token can’t go here. (-2740)` with both `killtask.arguments = ["-e","'quit app \"Transmission\"'"]` and         `killtask.arguments = ["-e","\'quit app \"Transmission\"\'"]`

Comment: My output for the argument is this: 
`-e, 'quit app "Transmission"'` which seems almost right besides the ,

Comment: One thing is, I believe its `'tell application "AppName" to quit'`, so the arguments should be `killtask.arguments = ["-e","'tell application \"Transmission\" to quit'"]`

Comment: The comma is there because the output prints the array of arguments (which prints a comma between every array element).

Comment: Hmm still not working :( The command I am trying to do is intact `/usr/bin/osascript -e 'quit app "Notes"'`. If you run this in terminal you will see it work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77142/discussion-between-schemetrical-and-dantdd).